# Android Studio font blurry

Tags: android-studio

I had both Android Studio and Intellij installed in my mac, however the font on Intellij looks OK but Android Studio looks blurry, tried many settings and re-install it still not work, does anyone face the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Oracle JDK7/8 does not have subpixel antialias as Apple JDK 6.

You could

1) install Apple JDK like this link says:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk

2) Or, since you have AppCode/IntelliJ  installed, they bundled with an modified OpenJDK that fix subpixel antialias issue.

You could do this in the terminal:

```
export STUDIO_JDK="/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15 EAP.app/Contents/jre/jdk/"
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

and Android Studio will use JDK bundled with IntelliJ.

3) If don't want to open terminal every time, just set STUDIO_JDK as user's environment variable

put this file studio_jdk.plist under your ~/Library/LaunchAgents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>setenv.STUDIO_JDK</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/bin/launchctl</string>
    <string>setenv</string>
    <string>STUDIO_JDK</string>
    <string>/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 15\ EAP.app/Contents/jre/jdk/</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>ServiceIPC</key>
  <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Logout and login, should work